# How to keep login user on an application in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an app that requires user to register.

- User opens the app, registers and logs in.
- Does some stuff with the app and closes it.
- Opens the app again, the user is recognized so he doesn't need to login again.

This is the code used for login:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data = dm.getAllRowsAsArrays();
        for (int position=0;position<data.size();position++)
        {
            ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(position);
             mail1=row.get(0).toString();
             pass1=row.get(2).toString();
            if((mail1.equals(mail))&&(pass1.equals(pass)))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),usermain.class);

        startActivity(i);
}

}
```

After login goto usermain activity, but if I press the emulator back button then I can see the login page with the details I typed for login.

How can I remove it?

Comment: clear the text before go the next activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` and then use this sample `onActivityResult` method in your login activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if(requestCode == LOGIN_CODE) { // this code you should provide in startActivityForResult
      this.finish();
   }
}
```

This will prevent you from going back to login activity. If you'd like to persist user's data, use also SharedPreferences as described by others.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if((mail1.equals(mail))&&(pass1.equals(pass)))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),usermain.class);
    finish();
   startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SaveSharedPreference 
{
static final String PREF_USER_NAME= "username";

static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
}

public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String userName) 
{
    Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    editor.putBoolean(PREF_USER_NAME, userName);
    editor.commit();
}


public static boolean getUserName(Context ctx)
{
    return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_USER_NAME, "");
}
```

in your main activity check this first:

```
if(SaveSharedPreference.getUserName(MainActivity.this).length() == 0)
{
 // call Login Activity
}
else
{
 // Call Next Activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreference` for that in your `onCreate()` methos like..

```
SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
if(sp.getInt("PREFERENCES_LOGIN", 99)==0)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);
    }else if(sp.getInt("PREFERENCES_LOGIN", 99)==1)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(GetLoginDetailsScreen.this,MenuScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }else{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);
    }
```

after login Successful add this..

```
         sp=getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit= sp.edit();
        edit.putInt("PREFERENCES_LOGIN", 1);
        edit.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

so here is your solution when the user successfully logged in set the shared preferences in your login class class like this

```
  //declare pref editor 
            SharedPreferences prefs; 
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefsEditor = prefs.edit();

    //paste below peace of code when the loginwill be success

                     prefsEditor.putString("remember", "yes");
                 prefsEditor.commit(); 

//now in your first activity you just check the shared pref value to know the user is logged in or not 


 SharedPreferences prefs;
String Log;
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Log=prefs.getString("remember", "");
//now check the value of shared pref and apply the condition like this
Intent intent ;
    if(register.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
            else
            {
             intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
```